# I need a beginners guide to setting up windows for python development

Tags: python, windows, development-environment

I currently work with .NET exclusively and would like to have a go at python. To this end I need to set up a python development environment. I guide to this would be handy. I guess I would be doing web development so will need a web server and probably a database. I also need pointers to popular ORM's, an MVC framework, and a testing library.

One of my main criteria with all this is that I want to understand how it works, and I want it to be as isolated as possible. This is important as i am wary of polluting what is a working .NET environment with 3rd party web and database servers. I am perfectly happy using SQLite to start with if this is possible.

If I get on well with this I am also likely to want to set up automated build and ci server (On a virtual machine, probably ubuntu). Any suggestions for these would be useful.

My ultimate aim if i like python is to have similar sorts of tools that i have available with .NET and to really understand the build and deployment of it all. To start with I will settle for a simple development environment that is as isolated as possible and will be easy to remove if I don't like it. I don't want to use IronPython as I want the full experience of developing a python solution using the tools and frameworks that are generally used.

Comment: Related: 'Setup Python enviroment on windows', http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182053/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that hard to set up a Python environment, and I've never had it muck up my .NET work.  Basically, install Python --- I'd use 2.6 rather than 3.0, which is not yet broadly accepted --- and add it to your PATH, and you're ready to go with the language.  I wouldn't recommend using a Ubuntu VM as your development environment; if you're working on Windows, you might as well develop on Windows, and I've had no significant problems doing so.  I go back and forth from Windows to Linux with no trouble.

If you have an editor that you're comfortable with that has basic support for Python, I'd stick with it.  If not, I've found [Geany](http://www.geany.org) to be a nice, light, easy-to-use editor with good Python support, though I use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) myself because I know it; other people like [SCITE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/), or any of a slew of others.  I'd avoid fancy IDEs for Python, because they don't match the character of the language, and I wouldn't bother with IDLE (included with Python), because it's a royal pain to use.

Suggestions for libraries and frameworks:

- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.org) is the *standard* web framework, but it's big and you have to work django's way; I prefer [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), which is also actively supported, but is light, gives you great freedom, and contains a nice, solid webserver that can be replaced easily with httpd.
- Django includes its own ORM, which is nice enough; there's a standalone one for Python, though, which is even nicer: [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org)
- As far as a testing library goes, [pyunit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net) seems to me to be the obvious choice

Good luck, and welcome to a really fun language!

EDIT summary: I originally recommended [Karrigell](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net), but can't any more: since the 3.0 release, it's been continuously broken, and the community is not large enough to solve the problems.  [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is a good substitute if you like a light, simple framework that doesn't get in your way, so I've changed the above to suggest it instead.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I currently use e! as my usual text editor and will use that I think for python development.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're thinking of setting up an Ubuntu VM anyway, you might as well make that your development environment. Then you can install Apache and MySQL or Postgres on that VM just via the standard packaging tools (apt-get install), and there's no danger of polluting your Windows environment.

You can either do the actual development on your Windows machine via your favourite IDE, using the VM as a networked drive and saving the code there, or you can just use the VM as a full desktop environment and do everything there, which is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

Install the pre-configured  [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) release from activestate.
Among other features, it includes the PythonWin IDE (Windows only) which makes it easy to explore Python interactively.

The recommended reference is [*Dive Into Python*](http://www.diveintopython.net/), mentioned many times on similar SO discussions.

Answer (score 3):

You should install python 2.4, python 2.5, python 2.6 and python 3.0, and add to your path the one you use more often (Add c:\Pythonxx\ and c:\Pythonxx\Scripts).

For every python 2.x, install easy_install; Download [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) and then from the cmd:

```
c:\Python2x\python.exe x:\path\to\ez_setup.py
c:\Python2x\Scripts\easy_install virtualenv
```

Then each time you start a new project create a new virtual environment to isolate the specific package you needs for your project:

```
mkdir <project name>
cd <project name>
c:\Python2x\Scripts\virtualenv --no-site-packages .\v
```

It creates a copy of python and its libraries in .v\Scripts and .\v\Lib. Every third party packages you install in that environment will be put into .\v\Lib\site-packages. The -no-site-packages don't give access to the global site package, so you can be sure all your dependencies are in .\v\Lib\site-packages.

To activate the virtual environment:

```
.\v\Scripts\activate
```

For the frameworks, there are many. Django is great and very well documented but you should probably look at Pylons first for its documentions on unicode, packaging, deployment and testing, and for its better WSGI support.

For the IDE, Python comes with IDLE which is enough for learning, however you might want to look at Eclipse+PyDev, Komodo or Wingware Python IDE. Netbean 6.5 has beta support for python that looks promising (See [top 5 python IDE](http://www.ninjacipher.com/2009/05/01/top-5-django-ides/)).

For the webserver, you don't need any; Python has its own and all web framework come with their own. You might want to install MySql or ProgreSql; it's often better to develop on the  same DB you will use for production.

Also, when you have learnt Python, look at [Foundations of Agile Python Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590599815) or [Expert Python Programming](http://www.packtpub.com/expert-python-programming/book).

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Can you explain what setting up these isolated environments does? Does it copy the runtime to the directory that you are developing in?

Comment: Note that ActivePython already comes with virtualenv/easy_install and its own binary package manager (PyPM); in future, it will include pip and IPython as well.

Answer (score 2):

- [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html)
- [SO: Python tutorial for total beginners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207701/python-tutorial-for-total-beginners)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/), read about [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) and [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/).
There's nice introductory Google tech talk about them: [ReUsable Web Components with Python and Future Python Web Development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ui-mSFuUZmQ).

Here's my answer to similar question:
[Django vs other Python web frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702179/django-vs-other-python-web-frameworks/926169#926169)

Answer (score 1):

Environment?

Here is the simplest solution:

- Install [Active Python 2.6](https://www.activestate.com/products/python/). Its the Python itself, but comes with some extra handy useful stuff, like DiveintoPython chm.
- Use [Komodo Edit 5](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/). It is among the good free editor you can use for Python.
- Use [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html). Its the best simplest short snippet editor, with syntax highlighting and auto complete unmatched by most other IDEs. It comes bundled with python.
- Use [Ipython](https://web.archive.org/web/20110823082301/http://ipython.scipy.org:80/moin). Its a shell that does syntax highlighting and auto complete, bash functions, pretty print, logging, history and many such things.
- Install [easy_install](http://google.com/q=easy_install) and/or pip for installing various 3rd party apps easily.

Coming from Visual Studio and .Net it will sound a lot different, but its an entirely different world.

For the framework, [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) works the best. Walk thro the tutorial and you will be impressed enough. The documentation rocks. The community, you have to see for yourself, to know how wonderful it is!!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I included a lot of links to frameworks, projects and what-not, but as a new user I was limited to 1 link per answer. If someone else with enough reputation to edit wants/can edit them into this answer instead of the footnotes, I'd be grateful.

There are some Python IDE's such as Wing IDE[1], I believe some people use Eclipse[2] with a python plugin[3] as well. A lot of people in the #python channel of FreeNode seem to prefer vim, emacs, nano and similar text editors in favor of IDE's. My personal preffered editor is Vim, but if you've mostly done .NET development on windows, presumably with the usual Visual X IDE's, vim and emacs will probably cause you culture shock and you'd be better of using an IDE.

Nearly all python web frameworks* support the WSGI standard[4], most of the large web servers have some sort of plugin to support WSGI, the others support WSGI via fast cgi or plain cgi.

The Zope[5] and Django[6] frameworks have their own ORM's, of other ORM's the two most well known appear to be SQL Alchemy[7] and SQL Object[8]. I only have experience with the former, but both support all possible sane database choices, including SQLite which is installed together with Python and hence perfectly suited to testing and experimenting without polluting your .NET environment with 3rd part web servers and database servers.

The builtin unittest[9] and pyunit[10] frameworks seem to be the preffered solutions for unit testing, but I don't have much experience with these.

bpython[11] and ipython[12] offer enhanced interactive python shells which can greatly help speed up and testing small bits of code and hence worth looking in to.

As for a list of well known and often used web frameworks, look into the following frameworks**:

- Twisted[13] is a generic networking framework, which supports almost every single protocol under the sun.
- Pylons[14] is light-weight framework aimed at being as flexible as possible and leaving all the choices about what ORM, templating language and what-not to you.
- CherryPy[15] tries to provide an interface to expose Python objects to the web.
- Django[6] attempts to be an all-in-one solution, builtin template system, ORM, admin pages and internationalization. While the previous frameworks have more DIY wiring together various frameworks work involved with them.
- Zope[5] is aimed to be suitable for large enterprise applications, I've heard nothing but good things about it, but consensus seems to be that for smaller you're probably better off with one of the simpler and smaller frameworks.
- TurboGears[16] is the framework I know the least about, but it seems to be mostly competition for Django.

This is everything I can think of right now, I'll edit and add stuff if I can think of it. I hope this helps you some in the wonderful world of python.

---

* - The main exception would be Apache's mod_python, which you should avoid for exactly that reason, use mod_wsgi instead.
** - Word of warning, I have not personally used these frameworks this is just a very short impression I have gotten from talking to other people about each framework, it may be wildly inaccurate. (If anyone has any corrections, do comment and I'll try to edit and fix this answer).

(The http:// is missing since they're recognized as links otherwise)
[1] www.wingware.com/
[2] www.eclipse.org/
[3] pydev.sourceforge.net/
[4] wsgi.org/wsgi/
[5] www.zope.org/
[6] www.djangoproject.com/
[7] www.sqlalchemy.org/
[8] www.sqlobject.org/
[9] docs.python.org/library/unittest.html
[10] pyunit.sourceforge.net/pyunit.html
[11] www.bpython-interpreter.org/
[12] ipython.scipy.org/
[13] twistedmatrix.com/trac/
[14] pylonshq.com/
[15] www.cherrypy.org/
[16] turbogears.org/

Answer (score 0):

Python has build in SQL like database and web server, so you wouldn't need to install any third party apps. Remember Python comes with batteries included.

Answer (score 0):

If you've worked with Eclipse before you could give [Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) a try