# For learning Python does it make a difference if I use 32 or 64-bit Python?

Tags: python, windows-7-x64

About to start going through the 'Learn Python The Hard Way' book and I am at the 'Installation' chapter, the book says to get 2.x... but should I get 64 or 32 bit? Does it matter one way or another? If so, how? I am running Windows 7 x64.

Thanks!

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue7206 this might help i Guess

Comment: Have a look at the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182053/setup-python-enviroment-on-windows .

Comment: Note the activstate windows installer, for any version and word size. http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 32-bit. Currently the 64 bit versions of python don't behave the way you might think they would (unless you've already researched it) and can create some installation issues with other libraries, especially on Windows.

For learning, 32bit is a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make much of a difference.  If you want to use specific libraries, they might only have installation packages for 32 bit and not 64 bit -- but more and more packages are offering 64 bit packages.  On the other hand, unless you are expecting to write applications that use more than 2GBs of memory, you won't need 64 bit support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the 32-bit version. You may run into issues because many libraries are only available in 32 bit and do not work with the x64 installation of Python.

The error messages aren't always very clear in that case either. I spent a few hours trying to figure out why OpenCV didn't work because of this.